# The ASE PCI-Bridge is not able to process the requested dispatching- Sybase

Tags: sap-ase

I am trying to install a jar file in Sybase ASE-15.7 using the 'instjava' command.

I am getting the following error: The ASE PCI-Bridge is not able to process the requested dispatching. This is a fatal error, please contact your System Administrator (SA) for help.

I have enabled java and enabled pci using the following commands:

```
sp_configure "enable pci", 1
sp_configure "enable java", 1
```

After looking at the error on the net, i have found that the cause of the error is :

```
Error 16022 may be reported "The ASE PCI-Bridge is not able to process the requested dispatching. This is a fatal error, etc." when the PCI is unavailable with a stack trace in the error log showing modules "jvminit", "SYB_CreateJavaVM" and "terminate_process" although the stack trace information is unnecessary.
```

But there is no solution to the problem.

would anyone be able to offer any assistance in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the `sybpcidb` database already?

Comment: Yes, sybpcidb was installed while installing the ASE server

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restart ASE?

Also I think sp_configure "enable pci", 1 requires that the sybpcidb database be created if it does not already exist.

Comment: I have tried restarting the ASE server also. While installing ASE, i checked on 'create sample database'. So, sybpcidb has been created and i can also view the stored procedures under it